# Why I can't access url localhost:9000/dummyTable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with react-router. I have three tabs. When I click on it in URL I have localhost:9000/dummyTable, localhost:9000/dummyChart. But I have an error `Cannot GET /dummyTable` when I try to write `/dummyTable` after localhost. What did I miss? Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

```
const getTabsTitlesInOrder = () => {
    for(var i = 0; i <tabsJson.tabs.length; i ++){
        switch(tabsJson.tabs[i].order){
            case 0:
                firstTabTitle = tabsJson.tabs[i].title;
                getFirstTabContent(firstTabTitle);
                break;
            case 1:
                secondTabTitle = tabsJson.tabs[i].title;
                getSecondTabContent(secondTabTitle);
                break;
            case 2:
                thirdTabTitle = tabsJson.tabs[i].title;
                getThirdTabContent(thirdTabTitle);
                break;
        }
    }
};

const getFirstTabContent = (firstTabTitle) => {
    switch (firstTabTitle) {
        case "Dummy Table":
            firstTabContent = DummyTable;
            firstTabPath = "/";
            break;
        case "Dummy Chart":
            firstTabContent = DummyChart;
            firstTabPath = "/";
            break;
        case "Dummy List":
            firstTabContent = DummyList;
            firstTabPath = "/";
            break;
    }
};

const getSecondTabContent = (secondTabTitle) => {
    switch (secondTabTitle) {
        case "Dummy Table":
            secondTabContent = DummyTable;
            secondTabPath = "/dummyTable";
            break;
        case "Dummy Chart":
            secondTabContent = DummyChart;
            secondTabPath = "/dummyChart";
            break;
        case "Dummy List":
            secondTabContent = DummyList;
            secondTabPath = "/dummyList";
            break;
    }
};

const getThirdTabContent = (thirdTabTitle) => {
    switch (thirdTabTitle) {
        case "Dummy Table":
            thirdTabContent = DummyTable;
            thirdTabPath = "/dummyTable";
            break;
        case "Dummy Chart":
            thirdTabContent = DummyChart;
            thirdTabPath = "/dummyChart";
            break;
        case "Dummy List":
            thirdTabContent = DummyList;
            thirdTabPath = "/dummyList";
            break;
    }
};

class TabContent extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={firstTabPath} component={firstTabContent}/>
                <Route path={secondTabPath} component={secondTabContent}/>
                <Route path={thirdTabPath} component={thirdTabContent}/>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
};

class TabButtons extends React.Component{
    render() { 
        getTabsTitlesInOrder();
        return(
            <div className="tabTitleWrapper">
                <div className="tabTitle">
                    <Link className="tabLink" to={firstTabPath}>
                        {firstTabTitle}
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="tabTitle">
                    <Link className="tabLink" to={secondTabPath}>
                        {secondTabTitle}
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="tabTitle">
                    <Link className="tabLink" to={thirdTabPath}>
                        {thirdTabTitle}
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class App extends React.Component{
    render() { 
        return(
            <div>
                <TabButtons />
                <TabContent />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>),
    document.getElementById('tab')
);
```

Comment: When you use the Link component, it make browser to do a client-side navigation. But when if you try to write url manually, your server gets request for '/dummyTable' and must return something.
what i mean is, it may be problem of server side, not client side.

Comment: You should be redirecting all browser requests to index.html so that it works normally

Comment: Are you using NGINX, Apache or Webpack?

Comment: I'm using Webpack

Comment: Have you looked into client vs server side routing (what godsenal said)? You gotta handle client side react routes in the backend with a catch all. This kind of question has been answered a million times here on SO and elsewhere, google it

Comment: If you're using webpack-dev-server, you can run it like this: "webpack-dev-server --port 9000 --history-api-fallback"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this routing issue in webpack, you will need to add this to your config object:

```
devServer: {
  port: 9000,
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: 'index.html'
  }
}
```